# Image not showing in page footer.

Tags: media, 7, theming

I need to display an image in the page footer using  tag. In my page.tpl.php I have  the following block.

```
<div id="copyright">
    <img src="../images/logo.png">
     <p class="copyright"><?php print t('Copyright'); ?> &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I can`t use print $logo since I can use another image for the logo.

Comment: Please edit the title, is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the current theme URL and concatenate it with your alternative logo

```
<div id="copyright">
    <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>/images/logo.png">
     <p class="copyright"><?php print t('Copyright'); ?> &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```